# Honoring project dependencies in AutoPlugin plugin's task?

Tags: sbt

I'm writing `AutoPlugin` with a single task. I'd like the task to be dependent on the same task in dependent projects.

So given:

```scala
lazy val projectA = project in file("projectA") enablePlugins(MyPlugin)

lazy val projectB = project in file("projectB")
    .enablePlugins(MyPlugin)
    .dependsOn(projectA, someOtherProject)
```

...then the plugin's task in `projectB` should depend on plugin's task in `projectA` (but not `someOtherProject` because it doesn't have my plugin enabled). How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ScopeFilter` for that. For example the projects, which do not include your plugin will have the task added by plugin undefined.

Therefore given you have a plugin, which outputs let's say project name. You can define a scope filter, which will search in dependencies of a current project.

```
val dependantProjects = ScopeFilter(
    inDependencies(ThisProject)
)
```

Now in your custom task, you have to find dependent projects, which have that task defined.

```
override def projectSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
  outputProjectName := {
    (outputProjectName.?).all(dependantProjects).value
    println(name.value)
  }
)
```

Because some projects may have the tasks undefined, like for example *someOtherProject*, you have to add a `.?`, which [as documented](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks.html#missing-values) *On a setting or task with underlying type T, this accepts no arguments and returns a setting or task (respectively) of type Option[T].*

The complete plugin code could look like this.

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object MyPlugin extends AutoPlugin {

  object autoImport {
    val outputProjectName = taskKey[Unit]("Prints project name")
  }

  import autoImport._

  val dependantProjects = ScopeFilter(
    inDependencies(ThisProject)
  ) 

  override def projectSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
    outputProjectName := {
      (outputProjectName.?).all(dependantProjects).value
      println(name.value)
    }
  )

}
```